# How to build a model requiring external package in PyMC3?

Tags: pymc, theano

I'm not sure if this is a PyMC3 question or a Theano question. I've used PyMC2 for a long time to fit a cosmology to supernova data. This requires some messy integrals (see i.e. http://arxiv.org/abs/astroph/9905116 )

So I use a package in python called Cosmolopy to do the integration and for some other convenience functions. Whereas this used to work fine with PyMC2, with the reliance on theano in PyMC3, I can't figure out if there is even a way to use Cosmolopy.

Here is some example code of my current understanding of how to build a model in PyMC3

```py
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
import cosmolopy as cp

# generate some redshifts
nSNe = 100
z  = np.random.uniform( low=0.0, high=1.0, size=nSNe )


# set cosmology and simulate some distance moduli and errors
cosmo = cp.fidcosmo
muSN  = cp.magnitudes.distance_modulus( z, **cosmo ) + np.random.normal( loc=0, scale=0.15, size=nSNe )
muSN_err = np.random.uniform(low=0.1, high=0.3, size=nSNe)

# pymc model
with pm.Model() as model:
    # omega matter is the free parameter in this simple example
    omega_matter = pm.Uniform( 'omega_matter', lower=0.0, upper=1.0 )

    # the cosmology as a function of omega_matter
    cosmo['omega_M_0']      = omega_matter
    cosmo['omega_lambda_0'] = 1.0 - omega_matter
    mu_fit = cp.magnitudes.distance_modulus( z, **cosmo )

    # what should be fit by the MCMC
    snr = pm.Normal( 'snr', mu = mu_fit, sd = muSN_err, observed = muSN )
```

This code crashes because Cosmolopy expects a float for omega_matter but receives a theano.TensorVariable instead.

So the question is two-fold:

1. Am I just missing something syntactically with PyMC3 that would allow me to do this (possibly because I am still stuck somehow on PyMC2 model-building)?
2. If not 1, then do I need to find a way to do the integrals in theano?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know well PyMC3, but I know well Theano. Theano use symbolic compiler and TensorVariable are such symbolic variable. You need to compile and execute the function to get a value out of it. I don't know where to do this in PyMC3. A fast thing to try that will work if the variable depend only on constant and shared variable is to do this call::

```
the_tensor_variable.eval()
```

This will compile the function and suppose it don't take any variable input and if it compile, it will run it and return the value.

Comment: I have tried TensorVariable.eval() and it just returns the eval() method but no evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

I think one possible solution would be to write a custom Theano Op following the instructions at http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/

I would write a pure Python op without support for gradient computation, in which you would only have to implement the make_node() and perform() methods.